# Trying to add a business in node express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add a business in Node Express Framework. My issue is that when I fill out the form to add the business, nothing adds to the page. Been trying to figure out this error for some time now.

**My business.js code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Business = require('../models/business');
var passport = require('passport');

// set up the GET handler for the main movies page
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // use the Article model to retrieve all movies
    Business.find(function (err, business) {
        // if we have an error
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end(err);
        }
        else {
            // we got data back
            // show the view and pass the data to it
            res.render('movies/index', {

                title: 'Business',
                business: business
            });
        }
    });
});

// GET handler for add to display a blank form
router.get('/add', function(req, res, next) {
// new
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render('movies/add', {
            title: 'Add a New Business'
        });
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/auth/login');
    }

});

// POST handler for add to process the form
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

    // save a new article using our Article model and mongoose
    Business.create( {
            name: req.body.name,
            city: req.body.city,
            province: req.body.province,
            postal: req.body.postal,
            street: req.body.street
        }
    );

    // redirect to main business page
    res.redirect('/business');
});

// GET handler for edit to show the populated form
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // create an id variable to store the id from the url
    var id = req.params.id;

    // look up the selected article
    Business.findById(id,  function(err, business) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end(err);
        }
        else {
            // show the edit view
            res.render('movies/edit', {
                title: 'Business Details',
                business: business
            });
        }
    });
});

// POST handler for edit to update the article
router.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    // create an id variable to store the id from the url
    var id = req.params.id;

    // fill the article object
    var business = new Business( {
        _id: id,
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content,
        date: req.body.date,
        rating: req.body.rating,
        actor: req.body.actor
    });

    // use mongoose and our Article model to update
    Business.update( { _id: id }, business,  function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.end(err);
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/business');
        }
    });
});
//get handler for delete using the article id
router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res, next){
    //grab the id parameter from the url
    var id = req.params.id;
    Business.remove({ _id: id }, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.end(err);
        }
        else {
            // show updated business page with redirect
            res.redirect('/business');
        }
    });
});

////auth check
//function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
//    //is the user authenticated>
//    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
//        return next();
//    }
//    else {
//        res.redirect('/auth/login');
//    }
//}

// make public
module.exports = router;
```

**My add.ejs code:**

```
<%- include ../partials/header.ejs %>

<main>
    <form method="post" action="add">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:*</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="city">City:*</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <label>Province:*</label>
                <select id="province" required>
                    <option value="--">--</option>
                <option value = "ontario">ON</option>
                <option value = "quebec">QC</option>
                <option value = "british columbia">BC</option>
                <option value = "alberta">AL</option>
                <option value="nova scotia">NS</option>
                <option value="manitoba">MB</option>
                    <option value="newfoundland">NL</option>
                    <option value="pei">PEI</option>
                </select>
                </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="postal">Postal Code:*</label>
            <input type="text" name="postal" required>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="street">Street Name:*</label>
            <input type="text" name="street" required>
        </fieldset>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>

    </form>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: in your `form action` use `/add` instead of `add`

Comment: I just get a 404 error. Tried many different options to make it work.